# Creating seperate weblinks for QA and dev region in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: database, web, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not very sure if there is possibility in SNOWFLAKE to create separate weblinks for QA and dev region.

Now we have one common link to access SNOWFLAKE in our company and we have QA and Dev databases built in that, I was just wondering if there is a option to create seperate web links for, one link for QA and one link for Dev.

Comment: How do your links look now?

Answer (score 0):

You can have "secondary" account setup, on a new URL that are part of the same bill, but they really are "another" account.

So the question becomes what value does this add.

With different URL's you can reuse the same SQL verbatim and not need to alter it per "region". You can also reuse the same use accounts. If you DDOS the endpoint (which uses to happen with 100+ connections) you also loss access to the admin control surface to make the instance big to handle "the increase in load" (this might have changed over the years, we last had this problem is 2017)

Re-using the same account but have prod-x/dev-x/qa-x users/databases/roles, means you have just one instance to admin. You have to use some region aware software to run/rewrite you SQL.

We did both at my old job. We started with all in one, and just handled it, but we did DDOS the endpoint and block ourselves from making it bigger till we found the tool that was just start new sessions, and run hard queries. So we got a second account (ignore the already extra account is different world regions) and planned to do all dev from that. But when we spun it up, we created some warehouse and back then the SQL commands didn't set a default auto off time like the UI, and some features where missing on the region, so we walked away from that instance for a month or two, and then got a bill with ~15K USD of server charges. Which was unpleasant. Anyways the dev instance never really got used. (the default to the warehouse creation was changed though). For our system having different account was really wasteful. Because to have data "always loading" and have dashboards always loadable for test (and multi-regions at that) means always have one extra-small always running, where-as when they where on the same instance both QA and DEV ran on the same instance, and given the total data load was so tiny, 1 instance was more than enough.

Which is to say, more instances leads to a lot of waste. If you like waste, and extra overhead, go for it. Many people come from a big-iron perspective, thus to avoid noisy neighbor problem, each thing needs to be it's own box, but that is just not an issue here. just use prefix's, and it's "all separate"